# How to get all rows that has same ID but diffrent value in other column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a trouble writing a query in PostgreSQL.
I have a View that contains `IDs` with `subID`.
for example:

```
ID  quantity partID 
100   50       10
100   20       10
100   30       11
101   50       13
101   70       13
102   20       17
```

I want to get all rows that has same `ID` but different `partIDs`.
for the given example I would like to get:

```
ID  quantity partID 
100   50       10
100   20       10
100   30       11
```

i tried this query query:

```
select id  ,quantity ,partid 
from A
group by id,quantity,partid
having count(id)>2
order by id
```

but it doesn't work. It accualty checks if `ID` appears in more than 2 rows... in the given example it will take `ID 101` as well. I also don't know how to make it choose only `partid` which are diffrent per `ID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `count` only `distinct` `partid` within each `id` group:

```
select * 
from A t 
where exists (
  select 1
  from A
  where id = t.id
  having count(distinct partid) > 1)
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/be1db/7)

Comment: please see edit. The order by is on `Id` not on `partId`... my bad. Any how your query just give one row with 100. there should be 3 rows.

Comment: take a look at the SQLFiddle your query returns one row with ID 100... there should be 3 rows with that ID... see my example in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to count; you only have to check if a row with a different partid exists:

```
SELECT * 
FROM atable t 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM atable x
  WHERE x.id = t.id
  AND x.partid <> t.partid
  );
```

Comment: It cannot have worse performance. (depending on the optimiser recognising the `count(...) > 1` or not. If it does recognise the count, performance would be similar)